# How to know the number of columns declared in a tabular environment?

Tags: tables

Is there a parameter or a way to know how many **declared** columns there are in a given `tabular` or `array`?

I need to know it just after the first use of `\\`

[image]

The main goal is to have a table with a tikzmark on each corner of each cell of the tabular, what I actually know to do. But for this I use a command that take the number of columns as argument. I prefer have this parameter automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{TikzTable}{md<>O{c}m}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \begin{#1}[#3]{#4}}{%
    \begin{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}}
}{\end{#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{TikzTable}{tabular}[b]{clrm{3cm}}\hline
a&b&c& 4 columns \\% At this point
\hline
1&1&1&1\\
\end{TikzTable}bob

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you looking to determine the number of declared or of actually-used columns? (As I'm sure you know perfectly well, it's possible to declare more columns than are actually used.)

Comment: Do you need the answer during or after the `tabular`.  What is the actual need or application?

Comment: See my edit : declared columns and in the tabular after the first `\\\`.

Comment: @mico 6 declared columns

Comment: Yes lualatex is welcome.

Comment: @Tarass - I've posted an answer with a LuaLaTeX-based solution. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can count the `&` in the generated `\halign` preamble

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{TikzTable}{md<>O{c}m}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \begin{#1}[#3]{#4}}{%
    \begin{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}}
}{\end{#1}}

\makeatletter
\def\zzz#1#2&#3{%
\ifx\zzz#3#1\expandafter\@gobble\else
\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{\zzz{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}#3}}

\def\zz{\noalign{%
\xdef\nocols{\expandafter\zzz\expandafter1\@preamble&\zzz}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{TikzTable}{tabular}[b]{clrm{3cm}}
\zz
\hline
a&b&c& \nocols\ columns \\% At this point
\hline
1&1&1&1\\
\end{TikzTable}bob

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the same idea as David, but with fancier `expl3` code; this makes `\nocols` available in every `TikzTable` environment, but the name is customizable in a trailing optional argument in case you need to nest those tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{TikzTable}{md<>O{c}mO{\nocols}}
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {%
     \begin{#1}[#3]{#4}
   }{%
     \begin{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}
   }%
  \noalign{\CountColumns{#5}}
 }
 {\end{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\CountColumns}{m}
 {% count the number of & tokens in \@preamble
  \regex_count:nvN { \cT\& } { @preamble } \l_tmpa_int
  % they're one less than the columns
  \cs_gset:Npx #1 { \int_eval:n { 1 + \l_tmpa_int } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN { nv }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{TikzTable}{tabular}[b]{clrm{3cm}}
\hline
a&b&c& This table has \nocols\ columns \\
\hline
1&1&1&1\\
\end{TikzTable}bob

\begin{TikzTable}{tabular}[b]{clrm{3cm}}[\foo]
\hline
a&b&c& This table has \foo\ columns \\
\hline
1&1&1&1\\
\end{TikzTable}bob

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed expl3 code is pure condensed efficacity.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It can handle `tabular`, `array`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`, and `tabulary` environments, as well as the `TikzTable` environment you proposed in your posting.

The number of declared columns of the most recently encountered `tabular`-like environment is stored in a Lua variable called `num_cols`. (Note that it's not necessary to do anything manually to obtain the number of declared columns for each `tabular`-like environment -- the calculations are done fully automatically.) To access this number from the LaTeX side, the code provides a LaTeX macro named `\numcols`.

The only input requirement is that the `\begin{tabular}...{<columnspec>}` material all has to be on one and the same line.

Note that the code is designed to handle cases such as `\begin{tabular} {@{} c >{$}c<{$} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\tt}p{1cm} @{}} \\` The column count will be "3". The solution method can also handle more-complicated column definitions, such as `*{6}{l}`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
%% next few lines from the OP's query
\usepackage{array,xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{TikzTable}{md<>O{c}m}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
    \begin{#1}[#3]{#4}}{%
    \begin{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}}}{%
    \end{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
-- Define a global variable (num_cols), set up two 
-- Lua functions, and assign one of them to the    
-- 'process_input_buffer' callback.

-- Initialize counter variable
num_cols = 0 

-- The next function computes the number of columns from
-- contents of string 'zz'
function calc_nums ( zz ) 
    -- retain the first "{....}" substring
    zz = zz:gsub ( "^.-(%b{}).-$", "%1" )
    -- remove outermost pair of curly braces
    zz = zz:sub  ( 2 , -2 )    
    -- expand expressions such as "*{5}{l}" to "lllll"
    zz = zz:gsub ( "%*%s-{(%d-)}%s-(%b{})" , 
                      function ( y , z )
                         z = z:sub ( 2 , -2 )
                         return string.rep ( z , y ) 
                      end )
    -- omit all stuff in curly braces
    zz = zz:gsub ( "%b{}" , "" ) 
    -- some more characters to ignore
    zz = zz:gsub ( "[@!|><%s%*]" , "" ) 
    -- Number of remaining chars in "zz" is the number
    -- of columns in the tabular-like environment.
    num_cols = string.len ( zz ) 
end

-- Next the main Lua function. Scan all input lines. 
-- If we detect start of a tabular-like env., lop off 
-- the prefix and pass the remainder of the input line 
-- to the 'calc_nums' function to determine number of cols.
-- ("%s-" means "0 or more instances of whitespace")
function get_col_spec ( s )
  local zz
  if string.find ( s , "\\begin.-{tabular}" ) then
     zz = s:gsub ( "^.-\\begin.-{tabular}" , "" )
     calc_nums ( zz )
  elseif string.find ( s , "\\begin%s-{array}" ) then
     zz = s:gsub ( "^.-\\begin%s-{array}" , "" )
     calc_nums ( zz )
  elseif string.find ( s , "\\begin%s-{tabular.}" ) then
     zz = s:gsub ( "^.-\\begin%s-{tabular.}%s-%b{}" , "" )
     calc_nums ( zz )
  end
  -- Do nothing if no match occurred.
end

-- Finally, assign 'get_col_spec' to the LuaTeX
-- 'process_input_buffer' callback.
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", 
    get_col_spec, "get_cols" )
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX-side code: a macro to print out the number of columns
\newcommand\numcols{\directlua{tex.sprint(num_cols)}}

\begin{document}

%% Example 1
   \begin{tabular} [b] { | * {6} { m{4mm }|} p { 12mm }|} \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\numcols\ columns} 
   \\ \hline a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}

\bigskip
%% Example 2
\begin{tabular} {@{} c *{2}{>{$}c<{$}} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\tt}p{3cm} @{}} 
\hline
a & b & c & \numcols\ columns\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
%% Example 3: the 'TikzTable' case
aaa\begin{TikzTable}{tabular}[b]{@{}cllrm{1.55cm}@{}}\hline
a&b&c&d& \numcols\ columns \\
\hline
1&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
\end{TikzTable}zzz

\bigskip
%% Examples 4 to 6: array, tabular*, and tabularx
$\begin{array}{@{}*{6}{c}@{}} \hline a & b & c & d & e & \numcols \\ \hline \end{array}$

\bigskip
\begin{tabular*}{0.5\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{7}{l}@{}} \hline
z & y & x & w & v & u & \numcols\\ \hline
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\textwidth}{@{}l*{8}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}r@{}} \hline
z & y & x & w & v & u & t & s & r & \numcols\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It did not appear yesterday while the 2 other did. I will reaper this injustice 

Comment: @Tarass - I've tried to be thorough with adjusting the calculations for various "nonstandard" items in the argument of `tabular`. Do let me know if I missed some tabular cases that are relevant in your documents.

Comment: I woks for me. I understand how you find the number of columns, but not how lua grab just the current table and not all the doc. Could you add array and tabularx support : tabularx works fine by changing tabular by tabularx in lua code, but array gives bad numbers.

Comment: @Tarass - Gimme a bit more time -- I'll post an augmented solution, which processes `array` and `tabular[xy*]` environments, in a couple of hours.

Comment: There is no hurry at all.

Comment: @Tarass - OK, I've updated the code to process `array`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`, and `tabulary` environments as well. :-)

Comment: This is great, as someone who much prefers Lua to primitive TeX and expl3, this opens a lot of doors. I would like to expand this concept to also allow the user to know which column they are presently on. My idea is to piggyback off of the input buffer, and could the number of `&` without a leading `\` between a new row. Does this sound reasonable? What does the `'get_cols'` string do in `add_to_callback`? Is it just a label?

Comment: @likethevegetable - "Does this sound [doable]?" Probably. Please post a new query, as your objective isn't aa subset of the query above.

Comment: Will do, when time permits. What does the `'get_cols'` string do in add_to_callback? Is it just a label? I tried adding an additional function to process the input buffer using similar syntax, but an error occurred.

Comment: @likethevegetable - The third argument of the `add_to_callback` function (part of the `luatexbase` library) provides a label of sorts; its main use when one wants to remove the function from a callback (via the `remove_from_callback` function).