# Access argument passed to environment with etoolbox \AtBeginEnvironment

Tags: tables, columns, etoolbox

I would like to use `etoolbox` to run some code at the beginning of the tabular environment. I would like to use the column specification in this code. Can this be done easily?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{...I want to do something with 'cc' (or whatever the column spec is)...}
%\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{something with #1, not surprisingly this fails}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
     hello & world  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know *what* you want to do with `cc`.

Comment: Good point--I was going to use it for a Lua function, no "printing" of the cc required. Being familiar with your posts, I suspect you'd provide an expl3 solution :)

Comment: Still we don't know what your *real* aim is. What would you pass and what are you going to do with it?

Comment: @egreg I was planning on using it to count the total number of columns in the tabular. I found a nice solution here, but I wanted to try it another way--I also feel that 'looking at' environment arguments could be useful in other scenarios.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418427/how-to-know-the-number-of-columns-declared-in-a-tabular-environment

Comment: You can't count columns by simply looking at this argument. It is easy to define a new column type which contains more than one column declarations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know there is more involved than just looking at the argument, you could use regex (as shown in the link).

Comment: but the argument is not \@preamble. How many columns e.g. has this tabular: `\begin{tabular}{lMzzz\blub}`  (and yes with proper \newcolumntype definitions this is a valid preamble.

Comment: That's a good point, Ulrike. Fortunately for my use, I would not be making column types that combine more than one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a little poking around trying to figure out what tokens are executed in what order with such a hook, and diagnostically print the first 2 (that follow my `\addmeafter` argument) out.  The second diagnostic token is key: `\csname`.  That means what follows is the environment name and is of variable length.  Thus, what I do is expand the `\csname` and pass the same sequence of tokens to `\zzz`.  By expanding it *once*, the 2nd token following my argument (aka `#3`) is no longer `\csname`, but `\zz` or `\tabular`.  Thus, by placing my desired `#1` argument following `#3`, it gets placed as if it were the first thing in the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\addmeafter[3]{(\detokenize{#2!#3!})\par% <--FOR DIAGNOSIS
  \def\tmp{\zzz{#1}}\expandafter\tmp\expandafter#2#3}
\newcommand\zzz[3]{#2#3#1}
\newenvironment{zz}{[}{]}
\AtBeginEnvironment{zz}{\addmeafter{Q}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\addmeafter{{|c|c|}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{zz}
     hello  world
\end{zz}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}
\hline
a & b\\ 
\hline
c&d\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out my diagnostics, and implement the hook as a macro `\tabcols`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\addmeafter[3]{%(\detokenize{#2!#3!})\par% <--FOR DIAGNOSIS
  \def\tmp{\zzz{#1}}\expandafter\tmp\expandafter#2#3}
\newcommand\zzz[3]{#2#3#1}
\newenvironment{zz}{[}{]}
\AtBeginEnvironment{zz}{\addmeafter{Q}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\addmeafter{{\tabcols}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{zz}
     hello  world
\end{zz}

\bigskip
\def\tabcols{|c|c|}
\begin{tabular}
\hline
a & b\\ 
\hline
c&d\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\def\tabcols{|c|c|c|}
\begin{tabular}
\hline
a & b & xxx\\ 
\hline
c&d& y\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I get the desired result, allowing me to pre-specify the `tabular` column format in the macro `\tabcols`, and not specify it at the time of execution.

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

On the possibility, as Don suggests, that I misread the question..

If it is not desired to stick in a column specification, but merely to read it in advance, the change is straightforward.  Here I read the column specification, `#4` in `\zzz`, and pass it as an argument to `#1` (which is the macro `\tabcols`), in advance of executing the `tabular` `#3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\readafter[3]{%
  \def\tmp{\zzz{#1}}\expandafter\tmp\expandafter#2#3}
\newcommand\zzz[4]{#1{#4}#2#3{#4}}
\newcommand\tabcols[1]{%
  The spec for the next tabular will be \detokenize{#1}\par}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\readafter\tabcols}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b\\ 
\hline
c&d\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & xxx\\ 
\hline
c&d& y\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**DOUBLE SUPPLEMENT**

The OP asks in a comment about `tabular*` and `tabularx`.  I will show how to address the two mandatory arguments of `tabular*`.   It is the same logic as the above solutions, but taken to absorb one further argument.  For example, compare `\readafter` to `\readtwoafter`, then compare `\zzz` to `\zzzz` and finally compare `\tabcols` to `\tabstarinputs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\readafter[3]{%
  \def\tmp{\zzz{#1}}\expandafter\tmp\expandafter#2#3}
\newcommand\readtwoafter[3]{%
  \def\tmp{\zzzz{#1}}\expandafter\tmp\expandafter#2#3}
\newcommand\zzz[4]{#1{#4}#2#3{#4}}
\newcommand\zzzz[5]{#1{#4}{#5}#2#3{#4}{#5}}
\newcommand\tabcols[1]{%
  The spec for the next tabular will be \detokenize{#1}\par}
\newcommand\tabstarinputs[2]{%
  The width for the next tabular* will be \detokenize{#1}\par
  The spec for the next tabular* will be \detokenize{#2}\par}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\readafter\tabcols}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular*}{\readtwoafter\tabstarinputs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a & b\\ 
\hline
c&d\\
\hline
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
a & b & xxx\\ 
\hline
c&d& y\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular*}{2in}{|c|c||}
\hline
a & big list of stuff here\\ 
\hline
c&d\\
\hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you shouldn't use \zzz. That's identity theft ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you steal a little, it's plagiarism.  If you steal enough, it's research! -Tom Lehrer

Comment: I think, though that you've done the inverse of what the original poster has asked. Rather than being able to write the argument from `\AtBeginEnvironment` he wants to be able to read the argument.

Comment: @DonHosek I have added a **SUPPLEMENT** to address your comment

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You've saved me the trouble of doing that myself.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The supplement was what I was looking for, nice job! If I wanted to replicate this behaviour for `tabularx` or `tabular*`, where I want to snag the second argument now, would you care to elaborate on how to do so?

Comment: @likethevegetable Thank you.  I will have to give some thought to the additional query

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes also very open to LuaTeX based solutions, I was thinking `token.scan_argument()` or the like might work?

Comment: @likethevegetable I don't understand lua, but I did provide a **DOUBLE SUPPLEMENT** that addresses the `tabular*` question.  Gotta go. Perhaps `tabularx` exercise is left to the reader.

Comment: @likethevegetable: I've updated my answer to manage column specification for `tabular`, `tabular*` and [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).

Answer (score 3):

The mandatory argument passed to `tabular` is really absorbed by another macro internally, so it's difficult to grab it naturally. You can, however, redefine `tabular` to grab that argument using [`environ`](//ctan.org/pkg/environ), or just intervene by redefining the initial `\tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\let\oldtabular\tabular
\expandafter\let\expandafter\oldtabulars\csname tabular*\endcsname
\expandafter\let\expandafter\endoldtabulars\csname endtabular*\endcsname

\RenewDocumentCommand{\tabular}{ O{c} m }{%
  Do something with \detokenize{#2} \par
  \oldtabular[#1]{#2}}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{tabular*}{ m O{c} m }{%
  Do something with \detokenize{#3} \par
  \begin{oldtabulars}{#1}[#2]{#3}
}{%
  \end{oldtabulars}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
  hello & world
\end{tabular}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabular*}{.5\linewidth}{c|c|c}
  hello & world & star
\end{tabular*}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{c|c|X}
  hello & world & tabularx
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The above examples provides the option to manage the column specification for `tabular`, `tabular*` and [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). `tabularx` uses `tabular*` internally, so no need to do anything else.

Comment: Great stuff. Why is plain tabular renewed as a command and not enviro? Also, why the abc counter?

Comment: @likethevegetable: Forgot the `abc` counter as part of debugging. And, it's actually needless to redefine `tabularx` since it uses `tabular*` internally. I've updated the answer to note that. It's easier to redefine `tabular*` as an environment, otherwise you'll have to do more `\csname`...`\endcsname` trickery to redefine the command, because you can't just do `\renewcommand{\tabular*}{...}`.